# Spring boot cannot access external files

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I am working with Kubernetes deployment. I have a spring boot application service running on one container and a file being shared by another container. The file due to file permission limitatons cannot be used by the spring-boot service app. Also, I cannot perform chmod OR chown on the file due to my access limitations. Will it be possible to add the external file in the spring-boot classpath so that the spring-boot service can access it easily?

Comment: Where is the file located and what have you tried to access it?

Comment: The file is created by another container in the shared volume(spring-boot application has access to this volume).

Comment: Ah now I understand. Adding the file to the class path would not change the situation. If the user that runs the process has no access rights then there is no wayy